# Can't perform require once in WordPress without displaying the path on the page

Tags: wordpress

Followng accepted answers given here I used the following to call some PHP code on my home page:

```
require_once (bloginfo('template_directory') . '/home_bloc_horaires.php');
```

It works, but it also actually displays the path of my template directory on my page! Any way to avoid this?

EDIT:
Tried `require_once(get_template_directory().'/home_bloc_horaires.php');` : it doesn't work and I get the following error messages:

```
Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in D:\EasyPHP\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mmt-2014\header.php on line 348
Warning: include(http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/mirail/wp-content/themes/mmt-2014/home_bloc_horaires.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in D:\EasyPHP\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mmt-2014\header.php on line 348
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/mirail/wp-content/themes/mmt-2014/home_bloc_horaires.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\EasyPHP\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mmt-2014\header.php on line 348
```

Answer (score 0):

`bloginfo()` outputs the result, which is why you can see it. Use this instead:

```
require_once(get_template_directory().'/home_bloc_horaires.php');
```

You can find more info on loading files in WordPress [here.](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/17/how-to-load-files-within-wordpress-themes)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work and I get error messages (added in my question).